# @rails-ujs How to intercept ajax:complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

In a Rails 6.1 application using `@rails/ujs` (no jquery), I'm trying to intercept when ajax requests are fired and when they are completed.

I have added the following to my `application.js`

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  document.addEventListener("ajax:send", () => {
    console.log('SEND')
  })
  document.addEventListener("ajax:complete", () => {
    console.log('COMPLETE')
  })
})
```

I correctly get `SEND` when I fire them, but when they end I don't get the (expected) `COMPLETE`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried ajax:done ?

Comment: Yes, same outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also show how do you send the ajax request?

Comment: With a standard link_to … remote: true

Answer (score 0):

I have some personal ideas to investigate this kind of bug.

clue: the SEND worked properly as it was printed in the console (Make sure there is no error message in the console)
idea: open the Network tab and check if the request is pending.
[image]

Because `ajax:complete` will fire no matter what result in the server responses, so we can use that to find the next step.

situationA: the request is pending.
nextStep: try to find out why the request stuck on the server-side

situationB: the request responses but the event still does not fire
nextStep: try to find if there are any scripts already listening to the rails-ujs events

- ajax:success
- ajax:error
- ajax:complete

and call `event.preventDefault()` inside. You can also open the `Source` tab and check the checkboxes to add break points at some specific XHR-related events:

- error
- load
- loadend

[image]
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#events

And try to find whether there is any errors there or call `event.preventDefault()`

I tested your code and it worked fine on my machine, so I just want to give you some ideas for reference.